# Copy data from one sheet to another based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets of data and I want to copy data from sheet 2 to sheet 1 based on a certain criteria. I have several regions and I only want data from the region "Africa" to be copied into sheet one. The code I have used for the same is as follows:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim workbookname As String
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet

    Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
      
    workbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    Workbooks(workbookname).Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Set wsSrc = Workbooks(workbookname).Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    Workbooks(workbookname).Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    ' Destination worksheet: Master Sheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks(workbookname).Sheets("Sheet1")

    ar = Array("Region", "Project Number", "Project Long Name", "PM", "KOB")
    arr = Array("Region", "Project No.", "Project Long Name", "Project Manager", "KOB")
 
    For i = 3 To wsSrc.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        If wsSrc.Range("O" & i) = "Africa" Then
            For j = 5 To 5000
                wsSrc.Range(ar(j) & i).Copy wsDest.Range(arr(j) & Rows.count).End(xlUp)(3)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
 
End Sub
```

This code runs but it does not give me any output. I am not sure what correction is to be made to get the right output. Any help for the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So here's a thought for you. If say `j = 10` then what are you expecting `ar(j)` or `arr(j)` to return since you only have 5 values in your arrays?

Comment: I want the output to be the data under the column headers to be copied from sheet 2 to sheet 1. The values in the array are my column headers

Comment: This is a code that I got from stack which I tried to modify as per my needs but I think I have some mistakes

Comment: You have a multitude of issues in this code which is why it does not work, the biggest being the array. You have 5 items in the arrays but your j loop starts from 5, therefore it can't find the value to grab. But even fixing that there are still others to change.

Comment: Is your headers in the exact same way in both sheets? If so please tell me what columns they are each in for both sheets. EG is it in A to E or A,B,C,G,H etc? What are they?

Comment: It is not in the same order in the both the sheets. 
Base sheet: "Region" - Column O, "Project Number"  - Column E, "Project Long Name"  - Column G, "PM"  - Column H, "KOB"  - Column L
Sheet 2 where data is to be copied: "Region" - Column B, "Project No." - Column E, "Project Long Name" - Column I, "Project Manager" - Column J, "KOB" - Column K
The headers in the base sheet are in row 2 and the data starts from row 3 where as in sheet 2 the headers are in the row 4 and data should be copied into rows 5 and after.

Comment: do you just need values to copy or the formatting as well?

Comment: Just the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a go with this:

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim WsSrc As Worksheet, WsDest As Worksheet, i As Long, CopyRow As Long

Set WsSrc = Sheets("Sheet2") 'Source sheet to search and copy from
Set WsDest = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Destination/Copy sheet
CopyRow = 5 'Starting row to put data on copy sheet

For i = 3 To WsSrc.Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'from row 3 to the last row in source sheet
    If WsSrc.Range("O" & i) = "Africa" Then
        WsDest.Range("B" & CopyRow) = WsSrc.Range("O" & i)
        WsDest.Range("E" & CopyRow) = WsSrc.Range("E" & i)
        WsDest.Range("I" & CopyRow) = WsSrc.Range("G" & i)
        WsDest.Range("J" & CopyRow) = WsSrc.Range("H" & i)
        WsDest.Range("K" & CopyRow) = WsSrc.Range("L" & i)
        CopyRow = CopyRow + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Should have stuck to simple coding as the one above. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help.